# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Delete Notmapped Cannot be null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I have an error when trying to delete a value here's how it goes.
My app has Surveys they have a One to Many relationship with SurveyQuestions which has one to Many relationships with SurveyAnswers. CascadeOnDelete works perfectly but when I try to do it with Ajax it sends an error

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: source

But it deletes the Survey and the related Questions and Answers perfectly, it just somehow sends that it's an error for ajax.

My Code:

```
   public JsonResult DeleteSurvey(int id)
    {
        SurveyViewModel survey = Mapper.Map<Survey, SurveyViewModel>(_unitOfWork.SurveyRepository.GetByID(id));
        if (survey != null)
        {
            _unitOfWork.SurveyRepository.Delete(id);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }

        return Json(survey, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Survey/DeleteSurvey",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {Id: surveyID},
            success: function (response) {
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                alert("Survey Deleted");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error");
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("Failed to upload");
            }

        })
```

UPDATE:

Got more info about error:

```
            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.<br>Parameter name: source<br><br>

        <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

Line 44:                     if (user != null)
Line 45:                     { 
<font color=red>Line 46:                     return Questions.Any(m =&gt;        m.Answers.Any(x =&gt; x.UserId == user));
</font>Line 47:                     }
Line 48:                     return false;</pre></code>
```

Here's that part in ViewModel

```
[NotMapped]
        public bool CompletedByUser
        {
            get
            {
                var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

                return Questions.Any(m => m.Answers.Any(x => x.UserId == user));
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the item been deleted, why would you return the item? And using ajax and then `location.reload()` is just pointless. Return a value to indicate success (or failure) - e.g. `return Json(true);` and then just remove the appropriate elements from the DOM

Comment: that was on my list of next thing to do, but I first wanted this thing to work, so what's the fix? could you maybe add your suggestion as an answer so I could understand more clearly?

Comment: The error suggests `Answers` (in `m => m.Answers` is `null`) but you need to debug your code to determine that. As for showing how you should be doing it, you will need to show your view (a typical row in your table assuming that is what your have, including the element that triggers you ajax call) and the function you calling (i.e. that contains that ajax call)

Comment: it's because Questions and Answers are null. And I'm for the suggestion about the error, not the change of location.reload() to removing appropriate elements, I can do that myself, but I'm asking about the error, what are your suggestions to fix?

Comment: You need to check for `null` values (as suggested in Ehsan Sajjad's answer,but I think that is irrelevant since it pointless to be calling that code (the `Survey` has been deleted so it makes no sense to return anything other than a `bool` indicating that it has. Its does not even make sense to map the data model to a view model)

Comment: Can you please add an answer how you would do it the best? (it's pointless for me trying to ask 100 of questions, it's better to just see a good example that you're indicating), I would be very grateful if you did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166236/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-highsepton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because the `Questions` is coming `null` after the deletions, you might need it to be instantiated so that it is not `null` but it would have no items in it or you can tweak your getter to consider it's `null` state as well like:

```
   [NotMapped]
    public bool CompletedByUser
    {
        get
        {
            var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            return Questions == null ? 
                   false : 
                   Questions.Any(m => m.Answers!=null && m.Answers.Any(x => x.UserId == user));
        }
    }
```

Comment: then `Answers` is also coming `null`